# CGoban 3 doesn't ask for saving a review!

Tags: go, kgs

I just finished a game at GoKGS and the opponent offered me a review. When we ended, the opponent has left first, then I closed the window with the review in a good hope CGoban will ask me if I want to save it - but it didn't! The review got lost!

Is it because the other player had the control? Is CGoban asking only the player in control?

Is there any way to recover the review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KGS has a *lot* of quirks, and this is one of them. The review is lost.

KGS will ask only the playing starting the review.

Also note that KGS does also *not* offer to save any games which were started by loading a local file. This bit me in the butt far too often...

Comment: Thanks mafu! Do they have any bug reporting system or something where we can send them, apart from their email (where it could get lost easily)?

Comment: KGS is not under active development anymore, it seems to have been mostly abandoned. There is a HTML client in the making, which is supposed to replace the Java client, but its progress rate is horrifying, if I may say so.